# Using persistent bottom sheet in fragment with relative layout parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have an activity with a coordinator layout as a parent, the activity is composed of a toolbar and viewpager tablayout. The activity has a fragment with a relative layout parent and nested in this relative layout is a recyclerview and a bottom sheet.

Now the problem is that the bottom sheet does not work well with the relative layout but the toolbar scrolls well on recyclerview scroll event.
However, when I use a coordinator layout as the parent of the fragment layout, the bottom sheet works fine but the tab fails to scroll hence the bottom sheet is not fully shown.

My question: How can I use bootomsheet in a relativelayout parent. Or can I still use Coordinator layout in the fragment and the parent tab still scrolls well?

Here is the code for the fragment with the relative layout as root layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <include layout="@layout/report_question_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for the fragment with coordinator layout as root layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
  <include layout="@layout/report_question_bottom_sheet"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code for my activity with tab layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Bookmarks">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />   

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I expect the toolbar to scroll out of view when scrolling down the recylerview items and scroll into view when scrolling up the recyclerview items.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [the doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetBehavior.md):

> `BottomSheetBehavior` is applied to a child of `CoordinatorLayout` to make that child a persistent bottom sheet.

`BottomSheetBehavior` works in tandem with `CoordinatorLayout` to let you display content on a Bottom sheet.